# How to find all cells matching a regex with gspread?

Tags: python, regex, gspread

So I am very new to programming and I am using python gspread module to use a google sheet as a database.
There's a function for said module called sheet.findall(query, row, column), and this is great, but there's one issue, the query parameter will only look for an exact match, meaning that if i write "DDG", it will not get me the info from a cell with the value of "DDG-87".

After reading the documentation, I found out that you can use python regular expressions to structure the query parameter, so I did that, but there's a problem; The second parameter in re.findall is WHERE to look for, but the issue is that the whole variable is the action of searching, example shown below:

```
search = sheet.findall(re.findall("[DDG]", The where to search goes here))
```

As you can see, the whole variable (SEARCH) is the search function, and therefore, I can not specify where to search.

I have tried to set the second parameter of the regex as (SEARCH), but obviously, it won't work.

Any idea or a clue on how I can set the second parameter of re.findall() to be self, or what I can do so that the function doesn't search for an exact match, but if it contains the text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gspread [docs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#finding-all-matched-cells):

> Find all cells matching a regexp:
>
> ```
> criteria_re = re.compile(r'(Small|Room-tiering) rug')
> cell_list = worksheet.findall(criteria_re)
> ```

So the following should work in your case:

```
criteria_re = re.compile(r'DDG.*')
search = sheet.findall(criteria_re)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Turns out I was reading the wrong documentation.